# Unable to change the css class of the current <nav>

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following `<nav>` inside my asp.net MVC core web application:-

```
<nav>
      <ul id="navigation">
                          <li class="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "Home", controllers: "Default")"><a href="/">home</a></li>
                          <li class="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "FAQ", controllers: "Default")"><a href="/home/FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                          <li class="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "Contact", controllers: "Default")"><a href="/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

and i want to change the class for the current link, i defined the following html extension method:-

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string IsSelected(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controllers, string actions, string cssClass = "selected")
        {
            string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string;
            string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string;

            IEnumerable<string> acceptedActions = (actions ?? currentAction).Split(',');
            IEnumerable<string> acceptedControllers = (controllers ?? currentController).Split(',');

            return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController) ?
                cssClass : String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

but when i click on any of the `<nav>` links they did not get any special effects! any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug to check if the IsSelected method has returned a cssClass. From your codes, it will just return cssClass when the current url is one of the below:

- /Default/Home
- /Default/FAQ
- /Default/Contact

Besides, the `<li>` tag 
 seems not have a built in `selected` cssClass, you need to define it somewhere.

I made a test based on your codes and just change the color:

`<nav>` in the _Layout.cshtml

```
<nav>
<ul id="navigation">
    <li style="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "Index", controllers: "Home")"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li style="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "FAQ", controllers: "Home")"><a href="/home/FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
    <li style="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "Contact", controllers: "Home")"><a href="/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Html extension:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string IsSelected(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controllers, string actions, string cssClass = "color:red")
    {
        string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string;
        string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string;

        IEnumerable<string> acceptedActions = (actions ?? currentAction).Split(',');
        IEnumerable<string> acceptedControllers = (controllers ?? currentController).Split(',');

        return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController) ?
            cssClass : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]